# I need html button to call controller method without js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it real?
I want something like this to work, this is part of html code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <input type="button" value="1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PayMonthMore", "Home")'" />
}
```

And this is my HomeController method to call:

```
public ActionResult PayMonthMore()
{
    DBModelContainer db = new DBModelContainer();
    var user = db.user.First(u => u.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    var paid = user.paidToDate;
    if (paid == null)
    {
        paid = DateTime.Now;
    }
    user.paidToDate = paid.Value.AddMonths(1);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }               
    );
}
```

Comment: yes you can do like this

Comment: but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put it in a form and remove the onclick then?

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <form action="/Home/PayMonthMore" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="1" />
   </form>
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, with this form, when I click on my button just nothing happens, no errors even if I change action to non-existing `action="/Home/PayMonthMore2"`

Comment: Can you change the type from "button" to "submit" and try again?

Comment: `The view 'PayMonthMore' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.` error

Comment: Did you create the PayMonthMore.cshtml in Views/Home folder?
It seems that your code called the controller but can not find the view.

Comment: No, I don't have this view. But do I need to create new View if I just want to silently call controller method?

Comment: If you want thing to be "silent", considering using Ajax for your call. That is a little complicated for your current skill.

Comment: If you don't have the view, you can redirect to the Index page.

return RedirectToAction("Index"); instead of return View();

Comment: thanks, this works, I'll try to deal with AJAX then.